# How to write DB2 commands

Tags: db2

Where do I write DB2 commands. For example I want to delete all rows in my table. I open db2cmd and paste command, and it does not work. Do I need to go to certain path in that db2cmd to commands to work?

Also commands in db2 command editor does not work either. Here is the screenshot:

[image: DB2 Command Editor]

Thanks

Comment: It is recommended to read the output of any DB2 command. It clearly says "There is no connection to a database"

Answer (score 2):

You can something like this from the command line (db2clp called in Windowd as db2cmd)

```
db2 connect to mydb
db2 select 'TRUNCATE table ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || tabname || ' immediate;' from syscat.tables where tabschema not like 'SYS%' | db2 +p -t
```

Or just this, if you know the table name

```
db2 truncate table db2admin.prisijungihai2 immediate
```

With this command, and if you have enough rights on the tables, you can delete any row in your database.

This is a fast answer as you were waiting for.

BTW, Control center is deprecated, now you should be using IBM Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to the DB2 database first with an [SQL CONNECT](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_connect.htm) command.

After you've finished reading the SQL CONNECT page, read the entire IBM DB2 manual.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have time to read entire manual. The only thing I need is to delete all rows in my table. Apparently it's impossible to do without command window.

Comment: Can't connect, maybe the problem is that Control Center is DB2COPY2, and db2cmd is DB2COPY1, just like here: http://i.imgur.com/FfxJWc8.png?1 how do I change db2cmd to be DB2COPY2?

Comment: We are not spoon feeding you DB2 answers.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.ii.db2udb.federation.overview.doc%2Fprod_overview%2Fiiyfointdctc.html  RTFM

Comment: I am not asking to spoon feed me. I just asked simple question why I can't write commands. And I am connected to database, I used connect function on Control Center.